# NetBeans - AngularJS project within a PHP project, all using the same git repo

Tags: php, angularjs, git, magento, netbeans

I just inherited an application that is Magento with an Angular frontend. The Angular code is wholly contained within a single subdirectory of the Magento application. I can set up a PHP project in NetBeans and I get PHP autocomplete and other goodies, but no love for the Angular .js files. The goal is to have both PHP development goodies *and* angular development goodies. All the code is in one git repo (else this would not be an issue, I could just have two separate directory trees).

NetBeans will not let you create a project within a project. I've tried stitching the codebases together with a symlink both directions, and either git doesn't like it (refusing to treat the symlink as a directory), or NetBeans doesn't like it (still seeing the Angular files as residing with the already existent PHP project).

Anybody have any ideas? Changing the repo structure (like using a git submodule) is not an option currently.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make "a project inside a project", that is correct. :)

In your project, check if in Remote Files (next to Source Files in the Projects tab) you have the necessary JS files. If not, you have to link to them in your project.

Also what version of Netbeans are you using? It should work in the latest ones (8.1 and up) but may not work in earlier (8.0 and below).